# Admin user change with unique email contraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using the unique rule on a request to ensure no duplicate emails are entered.

Looking at Laravel docs I saw how to ignore the posting users email, but what about an Admin who has the privilege of making an making a change to a user. I still want to check for uniqueness but skip the email of the user being modified not the admins email.

Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass the `id` of the user you are trying to modify.

Let's say in your controller you have

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $id) {
    ...
}
```

Then in your `UserRequest` you can retrieve the route parameter `$id` using

```
public function rules() {
    $id = $this->route('id') ?: 0;

    return [
        'email' => "required|unique:users,email,{$id}",
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the thing I needed. It even is the object when you use implicit bindings. Thank you.